# SelfSizing Cell only working for one prototype cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have two prototype TableViewCells. One is simply the copy paste of other for now. `BasicCell` and `BasicCell2` . I have just copied `BasicCell` for `BasicCell2`

Here is my Swift code

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && flagcheck == 0 ) {
        var cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell2") as BasicCell2!
        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = BasicCell2(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell2")
        }

        cell2.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        cell2.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("b2cecf")
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return cell2

    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0){
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = BasicCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }

        cell.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        return cell
    }
    else {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell!
        if cell === nil {
            cell = BasicCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }
        cell.titlet.text = self.data1[indexPath.row-1]
        return cell
    }
}
```

So as per the code the first if condition is satisfied for the first row and `cell2` is returned. And the first row is not getting resized. Here is a screenshot for the same. When I use only one cell it is working fine. Please don't ask me why am I duplicating cells.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: create cell with cellIdentifier if it is nil

Comment: Didn't get you. Any kind of code snippet would be of great help.

Comment: if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell2")
        }

Comment: I have updated my code. Output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether Cell is nil, if it is nill than you can intialize with `UITableViewCell` method, like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && flagcheck == 0 ) {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell2") as BasicCell2
        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell2")
        }

        cell2.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        cell2.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("b2cecf")
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return cell2

    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }

        cell.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }
        cell.titlet.text = self.data1[indexPath.row-1]
        return cell
    }
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: cannot invoke == with an argument list of type Basiccell nil literal convertible